# Counting records in another table that match criteria in PowerPivot

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

I've got 2 tables:

1. `RefundData`: contains details of Refunds (relevant column name: `RefundAmount`)
2. `Buckets`: 3 columns: `BucketLow`, `BucketHigh`, `CountOfRecords`

The Refund Amounts range from $0.01 to $25,000.00.

I'm trying to count the Refund amounts in the `RefundData` table that fall within each Bucket level in the `Buckets` table.

Some sample data:

```
RefundAmount
0.29
81.75
1000.25
1500.74
2154.55
125.52

BucketLow    BucketHigh    CountOfRecords
0            1000          3
1000         2000          2
2000         3000          1
```

What I've tried:

In the `CountOfRecords` field I've tried adding the following expression to count the occurrences of `RefundAmount` that are >=`BucketLow' AND <`BucketHigh`

```
=calculate(count('RefundData'[RefundAmount]),'RefundData'[RefundAmount]>=[BucketLow],'RefundData'[RefundAmount]<[BucketHigh])
```

PowerPivot is giving me the following error:

**Column `BucketLow` cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.**

What am I missing?

I feel like I'm really close but missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Minor syntax issue. The `CALCULATE` function in PowerPivot takes at least 1 parameter

1. Expression (required)
2. [Filter1] (optional)
3. [Filter2] (optional)
4. etc...

I had originally thought that I could merely place my filter requirements in the `CALCULATE` function like this:

```
'RefundData'[RefundAmount]>=[BucketLow]
```

But instead the filter parameters need to wrapped in another function: `FILTER`

So instead of this:

```
=CALCULATE(
           COUNT('RefundData'[RefundAmount]),
           'RefundData'[RefundAmount]>=[BucketLow],
           'RefundData'[RefundAmount]<[BucketHigh]
          )
```

The formula should look like this:

```
=CALCULATE(
           COUNT('RefundData'[RefundAmount]),
           FILTER('RefundData','RefundData'[RefundAmount]>=[BucketLow]),
           FILTER('RefundData','RefundData'[RefundAmount]<[BucketHigh])
          )
```